# cpp vector erase by indices too slower than python

Tags: python, c++, vector, stl

I want to delete items in vector by indices in cpp code. However it is too slow

1. cpp version

```
long remove_cnt = 0;
for (auto &remove_idx : remove_index) {
    mylist.erase(mylist.begin() + (long) remove_idx - remove_cnt);
    remove_cnt++;
}
```

2. python version

```
new_mylist = [item for i, item in enumerate(mylist) if i not in remove_index]
```

I expect that cpp is faster than python. But my cpp code is too slower than python code. Are there other efficient code in cpp??

Comment: questions about runtime mesaurements need much more details. A [mcve], all details about how the code was built, and all details on how you measured the time. Anyhow, most of the time its just about forgetting to turn on compiler optimizations. Did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: the snippets do different things

Comment: I don't know how python does it under the hood, but C++ vectors are basically resizable arrays. Meaning that each time you removed items 'from within', it needs to move all items that follow to fill the gap. And depending on the item you are copying that way, that can take a moment or three.

Comment: If you need a container for frequent inserting/removing, C++ offers `std::list`, which excels at just that, but will be slower while iterating over the data. It's all about tradeoffs.

Comment: Your loop is horribly inefficient, it has to re-arrange the items you keep for every removal. Something like `std::erase_if(mylist, /* predicate implementing criteria for elements being in remove_index */)` will be much faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a good example of why a 1-1 translation between languages usually doesn't work.

To efficiently erase items from a vector you don't do it by index.
Assuming you got your indices in python by evaluating some condition (a predicate). You can directly use this predicate in C++.
Say you want to remove all ints > 4 then the code looks like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool greater_then_4(const int value)
{
    return value > 4;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove
    // remove all values greater then 4. remove will actually move all those values till the end
    auto it = std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), greater_then_4);

    // shrink the vector to only include the items not matching the predicate
    values.erase(it, values.end());

    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "remove will actually move all those values till the end" -> remove will move values that need to remain ahead of values that should go, leaving the values after `it` in a valid but unspecified state

Comment: @Caleth Good clarification, my "standardeze" is not always spot on ;)